# For a string containing characters and numbers, how to add 1 to all numbers only

Tags: c#, path

Thanks for helping me!
I have a string list coming from a path file:

Data="M311.97458,250.39993 L213.97533,248.39996 222.37435,216.7998 C222.37435,216.7998 ......589.5753,173.99994
593.1753,179.9999 ......334.3039,253.21373 311.97458,250.39993 z" (the "......." is used for representing uncessary number")

As you can see, the characters (like "M" and "C") have some special meaning, and number pairs are for cooridinate. I want to add 1 to each numbers in "Data" without changing any other things. How can I do that with C#? I guess a `.split()` is useful but the "Data" is too hard for `.split()` only

Thank you!

Comment: By adding 1 you mean concatenating. i.e. `"123"` becomes `"1231"` or adding `1` to the number the substring represents as in `"123"` becomes `"124"`?

Comment: And is that SVG by any chance?

Comment: Hi Sticky! I mean 123 to 124. Sorry I didn't describe it clearly. Yes it's a SVG, and you can change the size of shape of it without changing its clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to identify the numbers within the string and replace them with a new value. For example;

```
var data = @"M311.97458,250.39993 L213.97533,248.39996 222.37435,216.7998 C222.37435,216.7998 ......589.5753,173.99994,593.1753,179.9999......334.3039,253.21373 311.97458,250.39993 z";            
var replaced = Regex.Replace(data, "((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+)", (match) => (double.Parse(match.Value) + 1).ToString());
// output: M312.97458,251.39993 L214.97533,249.39996 223.37435,217.7998 C223.37435,217.7998 ......590.5753,174.99994,594.1753,180.9999......335.3039,254.21373 312.97458,251.39993 z
```

So here the `Regex` pattern is identifying the numbers within the string by finding anything that's not a comma or space and is numeric with a decimal place in (so it won't work for integers, but you can adapt if required). Then effectively in the `Regex.Replace` we're looping through each match, and using a [MatchEvaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2) to add one to the number and return it to form the new string.

Comment: Hi Steve! Your code is wonderful! I wrote another piece of codes which is so long and not successful, but you finish it in one line of code!
I have another question, that could you only add 1 to chosen elements of every match? For example I only add 1 to every x in all the (x,y) match, not y. :)

Comment: You could do something crude, but as from your latest comment this is SVG, you'd really need to parse it properly.. not every command has an x and y, so it'd get messy using this approach. I'll leave my answer though as I think it does work for the question as originally stated.

Comment: Hi Steve! Thank you for your suggestion! This SVG is composed of lots of points drawn by me, so I think every point match has x and y. I never learned regular expression but it turns out to be really effective as shown in your code. Could you please help me change your code a bit so that I can only add 1 to x or y? 

Changing SVD.data is a really important function for me, becasue I want to change SVD.data constantly to make SVD move to some direction as I command.

I do try your code but it said that the output dosen't fit the "dataproperty". I'm trying to solve it out right now.

Comment: It's dirty, but you could change the Regex pattern (which I've added backslash escapes to already) to `((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+),`, that'll target any number with a comma immediately following it and ignore the others.

Comment: i.e. `replaced = Regex.Replace(data, "((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+),", (match) => (double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString()+",");`

Comment: Thank you! I run it and it works really well, except that the first number is not changing (namely the "311"). How come?

Comment: The first number gets incremented for me, is your input *exactly* as you have shown it - with the pattern as it is it'll be sensitive to any additional spaces before the comma for example.

Comment: By the way - this is a useful tool for seeing which numbers will be targeted: https://regex101.com/r/isGE8r/1

Comment: Thank you! The format of regular expression match the data of SVG really well in your link, but when I use `((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+), `, it doesn't match. I think it's just some small difference between visual studio and Regex.  Btw, in this code `replaced = Regex.Replace(data, "((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+),", (match) => (double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString()+",");` , I found that when I change `[1]` to `[0]` and `[2]`, it doesn't work any more. How come? I wanna change y in (x,y) pair too

Comment: By the way you can do all this using inkscape

Comment: Thank you Denis! Actually I'm doing this in "Microsoft Expression Blend 4". I draw a SVG and try to change it in this software using keyboard. So I need to connect the SVG and my keyboard using code. Is it possible that I combine inkscape and this software?