# How do I pull out the ”data" from a SVG, alter it, then put it back with correct format?

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, path

Thank you for helping me! I would like to change the whole data of a path (SVG) using code, so that I can move the position of the path to a specific direction. For example, steve helps me with the following code to add 1 to x in all (x,y) pair to move the path (SVG) to theright direction : [Steve's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675415/for-a-string-containing-characters-and-numbers-how-to-add-1-to-all-numbers-only/55675831?noredirect=1#comment98062419_55675831)  (but the first x (311) doesn't change. There is some bug)

```
var data = @"M311.97458,250.39993L213.97533,248.39996 222.37435,216.7998C222.37435,216.7998 ......589.5753,173.99994,593.1753,179.9999......334.3039,253.21373 311.97458,250.39993 z"; '           
var replaced = Regex.Replace(data, "((?=[^, ])\\d+\\.\\d+),", (match) => (double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString()+",")
// output: M311.97458,251.39993L214.97533,249.39996 223.37435,217.7998C223.37435,217.7998 ......590.5753,174.99994,594.1753,180.9999......335.3039,254.21373 312.97458,251.39993 z
```

After I get the output, I tried to put it into data. I wrote `a.SetValue(Path.DataProperty,replace)` and `a.SetValue(Path.DataProperty,Geometry.Parse(replace))`, but they both don't work. The result shows that

> Unprocessed error:  System.FormatException: the format of input string is not correct.

How can I alter the output into a correct format for the data of a path(SVG) ? Or should I change my previous code?

Thank you!

Comment: if you don't know how that works, use a tool for it... perhpas https://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 0):

Paths in WPF use simple geometry. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) everything about the syntax of that is explained. If you read and understand that article it will be much easy to go through your own Path and fix it the way you want.

Main commands:

Move command `M startPoint`  - or - `m startPoint`

Line command `L endPoint` - or - `l endPoint`

Horizontal line command `H x`  - or - `h x`

Vertical line command `V y` - or - `v y`

Cubic bezier curve command `C controlPoint1 controlPoint2 endPoint` - or - `c controlPoint1 controlPoint2 endPoint`

Quadratic Bezier Curve Command  `Q controlPoint endPoint` - or - `q controlPoint endPoint`

Elliptical Arc Command `A size rotationAngle isLargeArcFlag sweepDirectionFlag endPoint`
- or - `a size rotationAngle isLargeArcFlag sweepDirectionFlag endPoint`