# PathGeometrry for a lock icon - Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to create a `PathGeometry` for a lock icon in xaml. Are there any tools to help me with that?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55702862/2289942, otherwise check https://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Geometry works seems complicated, but once you understand how it works, you can use Vector-based icons that are better than images. Give it a try it.

You can use **Geometry** in this way.

First, A string-based Geometry value is required.

**M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z** **=** [image]

```xml
<Geometry x:Key="ICON">
    M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z
</Geometry>
```

And Path is required to print Geometry on the screen.

```xml
<Path Data="{StaticResource ICON}" Width="48" Height="48"/>
```

It is recommended that the Path size is the same as the Path actual size. Because adjusting the size with ViewBox is a way to better utilize the characteristics of Vector.

#### Finaly

below is how to apply this method to use icons.

[image]

*lock-outline*

```xml
<Viewbox Width="48" Height="48">
    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Fill="Black" Data="M12,17C10.89,17 10,16.1 10,15C10,13.89 10.89,13 12,13A2,2 0 0,1 14,15A2,2 0 0,1 12,17M18,20V10H6V20H18M18,8A2,2 0 0,1 20,10V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V10C4,8.89 4.89,8 6,8H7V6A5,5 0 0,1 12,1A5,5 0 0,1 17,6V8H18M12,3A3,3 0 0,0 9,6V8H15V6A3,3 0 0,0 12,3Z" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

[image]

*lock-open-variant-outline*

```xml
<Viewbox Width="48" Height="48">
    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Fill="Black" Data="M10 13C11.1 13 12 13.89 12 15C12 16.11 11.11 17 10 17S8 16.11 8 15 8.9 13 10 13M18 1C15.24 1 13 3.24 13 6V8H4C2.9 8 2 8.9 2 10V20C2 21.1 2.9 22 4 22H16C17.1 22 18 21.1 18 20V10C18 8.9 17.1 8 16 8H15V6C15 4.34 16.34 3 18 3S21 4.34 21 6V8H23V6C23 3.24 20.76 1 18 1M16 10V20H4V10H16Z" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

And the site below offers many different open-source icons. You can choose it yourself and provide it with Xaml source code. I also use this website a lot. [Here](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for a website like that!

Comment: @SaiyanGirl I'm glad you want what you want. :)